# installed thrift however when tried to run thrift command it says Thrift: command not found

Tags: macos, installation, thrift

I have installed thrift in mac.

From the terminal it looks like thrift is installed successfully however when i tried to run thrift command i got the following

```
Thrift: command not found
```

I used the whereis command from the terminal to find the location of thrift but couldn't find it.

Any suggestions?

Terminal output after installing thrift
thrift 0.9.0

```
Building C++ Library ......... : yes
Building C (GLib) Library .... : no
Building Java Library ........ : yes
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : yes
Building Ruby Library ........ : yes
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : yes
Building PHP Library ......... : yes
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : no
Building D Library ........... : no
```

Comment: You do know we can't see images that are in files on your local machine, right?

Comment: @KenWhite - i do know no one can see images that are on my local machine..

Answer (score 4):

I think you didn't actually install thrift.
You have to do followings after ./configure

---

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: actually there are other problems related to installation process on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and tried to execute

```
    $ make
    $ sudo make install
```

commands but got error

```
./src/thrift/cxxfunctional.h:93:18: error: no member named 'bind' in namespace 'std'
using ::std::bind;
~~~~~~~^
src/thrift/concurrency/ThreadManager.cpp:569:8: warning: private field 'firstTime_' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
bool firstTime_;
^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make[4]: *** [ThreadManager.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

after that found issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2229

and tried to install `thrift` from sources by instruction http://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource/, now all is good.

Maybe these steps will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with you.

But I fixed it by using HomeBrew to install it.

You can try with these links:

http://blog.evernote.com/tech/2012/12/20/building-apache-thrift-on-mac-os-x/
http://brew.sh